# Using Cache in Collatz Sequence implementing issues

Tags: c#

I have created 2 lists, one for the number and one for the chain count. If the number is in the number list, take it's chain count and add it to the current chain count. My issue right here is that the program stucks and it's not returning me anything. The problem itself it's solved, it takes me up to 4.7 seconds to find the number under one million that has the longest sequence and its chain count but I want to optimize it using cache memory.

```
static List<long> cache_number = new List<long>();
    static List<long> cache_chains = new List<long>();

    static long CollatzChain(long num) {
        int chain = 1;
        while (num != 1) {
            if(cache_number.Contains(num)){
                long x = chain + cache_chains[cache_number.IndexOf(num)];
                return x;
            }
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                num = num / 2;
            }
            else {
                num = 3 * num + 1;
            }
            chain++;     
        }
        cache_number.Add(num);
        cache_chains.Add(chain);
        return chain;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args){

        Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
        time.Start();

        List<long> chain = new List<long>();
        List<long> numbers = new List<long>();


        for (int i = 13; i < 1000000; i++) {
            numbers.Add(i);
            chain.Add(CollatzChain(i));
        }

        time.Stop();
        long elapsed = time.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("The longest chain was made by number {0} with a chain of {1} elements", numbers[chain.IndexOf(chain.Max())], chain.Max());
        Console.Write("Time Elapsed: {0} ms", elapsed);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```